# C program : changing data format of Queue with linked-list

Tags: c, multithreading, linked-list, queue

I'm planning to convert my python program to C program due to the processing time issue. The python program uses a multi-thread for parallel processing and Queue for data exchange between threads.

The python queue did almost everything by itself so what I do is just put(or enqueue) any type of data. It could handle bytearray, string, float list with a single queue.

That is what I want to build with C program's linked-list since my data has various types and lengths. However, the majority of linked-list example what I found always contains a fixed-length int array or single char.

More specifically, I want to make the node's structure can recognize the enqueued data type and length so that it can dynamically allocate the memory.

Here's an example of my data

- Action - Thread1 enqueue 3 times and each item contains:
  item 1 : datetime info, string array ex) 2020-06-28-19:00:00
  item 2 : header info, string array ex)
  3#20#1290#125#333#666#12#3#12\n
  item 3 : data, float array  ex) [37749.00, 39922.00, ... , 274003.00]

Is it possible or is there any efficient way to handle above action with the C programming?

Actually the data exchanging is the key part of my multi-thread program therefore I need to solve this problem. Thanks.

Comment: Are you even sure the Python processing issue is something you cannot fix in Python alone, and therefore need to convert to C?

Comment: I hope so. Frankly speaking, I cannot imagine how much C would be faster. However, from the beginning, this project was planned to use C, so I have to build with it. I know current situation seems a bit meaningless but there is no choice.